Why USB chargers with two ports capable of more than 15 W can often only deliver 15 W when charging two devices?
There are many chargers that can output over 30 W over USB (at different voltages and current). Some of these charges have a USB-C and USB-A port on them, allowing for simultaneous charging of two devices. However, in practice, the power delivered to both devices together is then capped at 15 W (5V and 3A). Why is that? Is that something to do with the USB standard, or would there need to be more components to deliver this? The charger already must have everything to support more power, why cannot it be shared so each device would get something like 15 W?
For example this charger: https://www.xtorm.eu/products/35w-gan-ultra-wall-charger
(the marketing says: "When powering multiple devices simultaneously, the maximum output is distributed across the ports." but that is not true, only 15 W for both devices is delivered, as attested by my phone charging roughly twice as slow as opposed to a charging it with my normal charger. All the other lightweight chargers I looked into share the same limitation.)
(I am looking at this from a hiker's perspecitve, so I want something light but at the same time fast so that I could for example charge my devices during longer lunch.)
Edit: I have two more devices sharing the same issue, they have the output parametres displayed, both support higher voltage then 5 V on USB-A.


The devices are also limited in the amount of power they will accept. As for a hiker, then have one of those solar panels that sit on top of your rucksack...

We cannot possibly know why some/all devices don't work for you as advertised. We cannot know how they work internally or how you try to use them, i.e. with which devices and what protocols they support to request different voltages and power levels, and what levels they would even try to negotiate alone or when charger has multiple devices connected.

Actually getting 35W requires USB-PD providing more than 5v, but since USB-A is limited (officially) to 5v and since there's only one output driver, it's 5V to both, and thus 3A/each, and thus 30W. If it had 2 USB-C ports w/PD, then both ports would be able to share the full power at different voltages.

@SolarMike I hear they are getting better than they used to, I should look into getting one (though it depends a lot on local climate)

@dandavis Hm, and so unofficially these devices (I added two more to the answer that list the voltages) support more than 5V on USB-A  when only USV-A is used, but when shared, they only stick to the official maximum voltage, hm?

@sup that would work, you just can't have 2 different voltages, even for an instant, which is why in that case, the usb-c wouldn't work as it couldn't boot at 5v until PD (or QC, etc) negotiated a different voltage, even if it were the same as the USB-A was using the whole time...

I can not answer authoritatively for your specific device and we can only guess when it comes to a proprietary gadget, but another device that I have with multiple ports is limited in a similar way, and the limitation is documented.
The problem is that with multiple devices attached, you will only get the maximum voltage that the "worst" port can supply. In my device's case, the USB-A only does up to 5 volts, so the USB-C port is then also limited to that.
This is not a USB design limitation but rather a design choice to make the product contain fewer parts. I have another USB charger with five outputs, and they are all completely independent. One can be at 20 volt, another at 9, and a third at 5.

Thanks, I think this is probably the answer. However, the devices (I tried 4 so far and all share this limitation - but I saw some that are twice as heavy that claim not to) support higher voltages on USB-A (I added a picture to the question documenting that). So they only break the rules when only one port is used.

@sup Well if you really need one with different levels, this is the one I use. Not really portable...

It's most likey the upstream regulator that is the limiter and they likely only have one. Many devices including PSE POE equiptment operate this way. It makes the devices cheaper because they only need one 15W supply instead of a 30W supply which is more expensive. The designers are counting that most devices are not using the full 15W.

Aha, and since when there are two different devices, they cannot agree on higher voltage than the standard 5V/3A  and so that is what gets used. I wonder if one had two identical phones or other devices, the situation would be different.
